# Search through dataGridView using multiple checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, search, checkbox, import, datagrid

I have started to create an app which will eventually give someone the option to select multiple year groups and collate a list of email addresses.

So far I have imported an excel file into a dataGridView box and managed to filter out items however, lets say for example i filter 'Year 7'. As soon as i select 'Year 8' the previous search disappears. Sometimes I will need to select Year 7, 8 and 9 together.

This is what i have so far.

Initially i thought i could create an if statement but it seems that it just searches whatever the last thing in the statement is.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim path As String = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Username finder\data.xlsx"
Dim dv As DataView


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [usernames$]", MyConnection)

        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)

        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub


Private Sub CheckBoxY7_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxY7.CheckedChanged

    ' dv = New DataView(dataSet.Tables(0), "Year = '7' ", "Surname Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    ' DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxY8_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxY8.CheckedChanged
    ' dv = New DataView(dataSet.Tables(0), "Year = '8' ", "Surname Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    ' DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you check a checkbox, the DataView loses the previous RowFilter. What you want to do is build the RowFilter using all checked CheckBox controls. Take a look at this example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [usernames$]", MyConnection)

        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)

        MyConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

    CheckBoxY7.Tag = "7"
    CheckBoxY8.Tag = "8"
    'etc...
End Sub

Private Sub Year_CheckBox_CheckChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxY7.Checked, CheckBoxY8.Checked
  Dim row_filter As String = String.Join(" AND ", (From cb As CheckBox In {CheckBoxY7, CheckBoxY8} Where cb.Checked Select $"Year = '{cb.Tag.ToString()}'").ToArray())
  DataGridView1.DataSource = New DataView(dataSet.Tables(0), row_filter, "Surname Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
End Sub
```

Comment: I see the method that you have used but it still gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for those who replied.

I have completed a solution by adding a tag to the property and writing a for loop.

```
    For Each ctrl In Panel1.Controls
        If (ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(CheckBox)) Then
            chkbox = ctrl
            If chkbox.Checked = True Then
                If FirstLoop Then
                    qstring = ctrl.Tag
                    FirstLoop = False
                Else
                    qstring = qstring & " or " & ctrl.Tag
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ResultBox.Text = qstring
    dv = New DataView(dataSet.Tables(0), qstring, "Surname Desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```